# My floating icon goes behind contents of my website

Tags: css

I am trying to add a floating icon in my website. The code I used is
html

```
<a href="#" class="floata">
<i class="fa fa-plus my-floata"></i>
</a>
```

css

```
.floata{
    position:fixed;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    bottom:40px;
    right:40px;
    background-color:#0C9;
    color:#FFF;
    border-radius:50px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
}

.my-floata{
    margin-top:22px;
}
```

In mobile and sometimes in pc it shows behind website content in my site at https://demo.justinechacko.in/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), this is for specifying the layer on which the node is drawn.

At your homepage, `3` was needed to be over the pictures:

```css
.floata {
  z-index: 3;
}
```